# Route polyline is not displaying in real time

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, polyline

My google map only shows created polylines when the app is resumed from the background processes (e.g: the screen is turned off then turned on, or a pop-up window was dismissed)

How can I display the polylines in real time, as the user moves? What seems to be the problem here? Here is my code: Any help? Thank you so much!

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {


public Polyline lineRoute;
int flag;
LatLng prev = new LatLng(0, 0);
List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

private boolean drawTrack = true;
private PolylineOptions routeOpts = null;
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private GoogleMap mMap; 
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
 private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    lineRoute = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    points = lineRoute.getPoints();
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    points.add(latLng);
    lineRoute.setPoints(points);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 25));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
         * user with the error.
         */
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}
}
```

Comment: hi, the code is a bit messy and not enought to understand why you can't see the polyline.
Please put some code, expecially rectOptions which is not created in this method but is used for adding the polyline.

Comment: @NDorigatti hi! I already put the codes for the activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing correctly because on any "handleNewLocation" you:
Create a new list of points (which is empty obviously)
then you get current location, put to this empty list. Clear the previous polyline and show a polyline with the points filled right before (which is a list with one point); that's why is empty.
In order to see it correctly you can either keep points outside the scope of the function or avoid clearing the map, and instead use the "lineRoute" parameter for adding the points.

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = lineRoute.getPoints(); // getPoints() gives you a COPY of the points
    //points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    //mMap.clear();
    points.add(latLng);
    //rectOptions.addAll(points);
    //mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
    lineRoute.setPoints(points);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 25));
}
```

this should help you.
Obviously i did not cover clearing the polyline etc which depends on your application logic

Comment: Thanks @NDorigatti ! I tried that but it is still giving the same result :/ Is it something to do with built-in onLocationChange() function?

Comment: Oh yes, i did non look it. You have to implement the onlocationchange and call the previously written funciton at every change. I suggest you to read the official documentation on location!

Comment: Actually, I included it containing the same codes as the handleNewLocation function. But still doing the same thing. @NDorigatti

Comment: can you re-post the whole code? Did you try to put a log in the "handleNewLocation" code and check it is continuosly hit in the logcat?
If you are inside and don't move, you don't get location updates

Comment: Everything is working fine now. I don't know what happened but I just uninstall and reinstalled the app after using your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Oh no. I don't know what is happening. At some point in time, the route is displaying while moving but when I tried to test it again this time, it's not displaying again the route. I've just re-posted the whole code @Ndorigatti. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to put some Log.i and check what is called and what not?

Comment: Oh. I haven't @Ndorigatti I don't know what log.i does and where shall I put it?

Comment: You have one line of logging right at the end of the else in onConnectionFailed().
It basically logs what you want in the logcat of the device. If you don't know what logcat is I highly suggest you to check it out on the official android documentation before going on with your error!

Comment: I know logcat. But what I mean is that the log.i on that line only shows error in connection. And I did not see any errors on that in the logcat @NDorigatti

Comment: Ok so add some other log lines all ovrr the code and check which log are shown and which are not

Comment: It only logs in the handlenewlocation() meaning, it only enters at that function and not in the onLocationChanged() and it only prints the logs whenever I tried to "minimize" the app to the background and resumes it after. @NDorigatti. Clearly, I don't know what is the problem all about.

Comment: Ok, clearly in your onConnected location you are not firing up the requestLocationUpdates because you check for last location, and if it iss not null you only process that location. Just fire the "requestLocationUpdates" always, even if you have a previous known location:
---------------------------
if (location != null) {  handleNewLocation(location);  }; LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
---------------------------

Comment: OMG!!!! IT IS! You're a lifesaver. I did not notice that. Thank you very much! @NDorigatti

Comment: So you owe me a beer when I'll come to your country ;)
Glad you fixed it!

Comment: Of course! Sure sure! :) Thanks again! :) @NDorigatti

Answer (score 0):

```
Try on this way.

package com.ibl.googlemap;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.ibl.comman.GPSTracker;
import com.ibl.foodpulse.CreateShareDeal;
import com.ibl.foodpulse.R;

public class ViewMapDirection extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnClickListener {

private GoogleMap map;
private ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
private Button btnShow;
private double ans;

private GPSTracker gps;
private double latitude2, latitude, longitude;
private double longitude2;
private int bcid;
private int vuid;
String res = "";
String url2;

Boolean checknet = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.googlemap_only_activity);
    gps = new GPSTracker(ViewMapDirection.this);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    latitude = b.getFloat("lat"); // hear i got lat lng from last activity.
    longitude = b.getFloat("longy");
    Log.e("View Map Direction", "get the Lat and Lng :" + latitude + " :: "
            + longitude);

    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        latitude2 = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude2 = gps.getLongitude();
        // hear i will got current location from GPS Tracker
        Log.e("View Map Direction ", " get Current Lat lng " + latitude2
                + " lng " + longitude2);
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert(ViewMapDirection.this);
    }

    Intent j = getIntent();
    bcid = j.getIntExtra("BCARD_ID", 0);
    vuid = j.getIntExtra("VUID1", 0);
    btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_onlywebview_close);
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_googlemapAct);

    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    map = fm.getMap();
    /*
     * db=new MyDBHandler(this); gp=db.getGPSdata(bcid);
     */
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(this);

}

// Initializing
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + ","
            + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Start

    int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
    double lat1 = origin.latitude;
    double lat2 = dest.latitude;
    double lon1 = origin.longitude;
    double lon2 = dest.longitude;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult = Radius * c;
    double km = valueResult / 1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter = valueResult % 1000;
    int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
    Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
            + " Meter   " + meterInDec);
    ans = Radius * c;
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result" + ans,
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // End

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
            + output + "?" + parameters;

    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the
    // activity_main

    if (map != null) {
        Log.e(" in View Map ", " in On Resume Method calling .........");
        // if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        // latitude2 = gps.getLatitude();
        // longitude2 = gps.getLongitude();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Card Lattitude is "+gp.getGps_lattitude()+" LOngitude is "+gp.getGps_longitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LatLng CardPoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        // LatLng CardPoint=new
        // LatLng(21.237425849325856,72.8330023214221);

        Log.e(" in View Map ", " in On Card Point........."
                + CardPoint.latitude);

        MarkerOptions Destpoint = new MarkerOptions();
        Destpoint.position(CardPoint);
        map.addMarker(Destpoint);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CardPoint, 10));
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Visitor Lattitude is "+latitude2+" LOngitude is "+longitude2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LatLng UserPoint = new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2);
        MarkerOptions Sourcepoint = new MarkerOptions();
        Sourcepoint.position(UserPoint);
        map.addMarker(Sourcepoint);

        String url = getDirectionsUrl(UserPoint, CardPoint);
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        downloadTask.execute(url);
        // } else {
        // gps.showSettingsAlert(ViewMapDirection.this);
        // }
    }
}

// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";
        Log.e(" in View Map ",
                " in Download Task  ........." + url.toString());
        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
        Log.e(" in View Map ", " in on Post  .........");
        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
        Log.e(" in View Map ", " in parser Task Calling  .........");
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result)     {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        Log.e(" in View Map ", " in parser post ........." + result.size());
        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Log.e(" in View Map ", " in Result For .........");
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            Log.e(" in View Map ", " in path  ........." + path.size());
            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                Log.e("in View Direction ", " lag ,,,,, " + lat
                        + " lng ... " + lng);
                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(4);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        // if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        // latitude2 = gps.getLatitude();
        // longitude2 = gps.getLongitude();
        if (map != null) {
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                latitude2 = gps.getLatitude();
                longitude2 = gps.getLongitude();

                Log.e("View Map Direction ", " get Current Lat lng "
                        + latitude2 + " lng " + longitude2);
                if ((latitude != 0) && (longitude != 0)) {
                    map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
                }
            } else {
                gps.showSettingsAlert(ViewMapDirection.this);
            }
        }
        // } else {
        // gps.showSettingsAlert(ViewMapDirection.this);
        // }
        // onResume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_onlywebview_close:
        finish();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

}

this another class for the comman for the pass ...

```
package com.ibl.googlemap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

/**
 * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and
 * longitude
 */
public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
            jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            /** Traversing all legs */
            for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps
                            .get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat",
                                Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                        hm.put("lng",
                                Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return routes;
}

/**
 * Method to decode polyline points Courtesy :
 * http://jeffreysambells.com/2010
 * /05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
 * */
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

}